Why does Sarah just give up in Call of Cthulhu (2018)?
In the 'It's Over' ending of Call of Cthulhu (2018), if the protagonist merely quietly refuses to participate in the ritual (instead of violently resisting), Sarah Hawkins just gives up on the whole plan and steps off the cliff. Why?
